# I got huge memory leak in spring batch

Tags: java, spring, memory-leaks, spring-batch, out-of-memory

I found a memory leak in my spring batch code. Just when I run the code below. Some people seem to say that jobexplorer causes a memory leak. Should I not use jobexplorer? thanks for the help.

At boot :
[image]

Just 5 min later : 5gb more memory consumption

[image]

And 1 hour later, It's kills some process by oom kill.

I use

```
java 11
spring boot 2.7.1
spring-boot-starter-batch 2.4.0
```

This is my code.
spring-batch processConfiguration and some class.
-BlockProcessConfiguration
-jobValidator

```
BlockProcessConfiguration
```

```
@Configuration
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
@Profile("block")
public class BlockProcessConfiguration {

@Value("${isStanby:false}")
private Boolean isStanby;

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 500)
    public String launch() throws JobInstanceAlreadyCompleteException, JobExecutionAlreadyRunningException, JobParametersInvalidException, JobRestartException {
        if (isStanby != null && isStanby) {
            Boolean isRunningJob = jobValidator.isExistLatestRunningJob(JOB_NAME, 5000);
            if (isRunningJob) {
                return "skip";
            }
        }

        return "completed";
    }
```

```
jobValidator
```

```
import java.util.*;

@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
@Component
public class JobValidator {
    public enum batchMode {
        RECOVER, FORWARD
    }
    private final JobExplorer jobExplorer;

    public Boolean isExistLatestRunningJob(String jobName, long jobTTL) {
        List<JobInstance> jobInstances = jobExplorer.findJobInstancesByJobName(jobName, 0, 10000);
        if (jobInstances.size() > 0) {
            List<JobExecution> jobExecutions = jobExplorer.getJobExecutions(jobInstances.get(0));
            jobInstances.clear();
            if (jobExecutions.size() > 0) {
                JobExecution jobExecution = jobExecutions.get(0);
                jobExecutions.clear();
//                boolean isRunning = jobExecution.isRunning();
                Date createTime = jobExecution.getCreateTime();
                long now = new Date().getTime();
                long timeFrame =  now - createTime.getTime();
                log.info("createTime.getTime() : {}", createTime.getTime());
                log.info("isExistLatestRunningJob found jobExecution :  id, status, timeFrame, jobTTL : {}, {}, {}, {}", jobExecution.getJobId(), jobExecution.getStatus(), timeFrame, jobTTL);
//                if (jobExecution.isRunning() && (now.getTime() - createTime.getTime()) < jobTTL) {
                if ( timeFrame < jobTTL ) {
                    log.info("isExistLatestRunningJob result : {}", true);
                    log.info("Job is already running, skip this job, job name : {}", jobName);
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    public Boolean isExecutableJob(String jobName, String paramKey, Long paramValue) {
        List<JobInstance> jobInstances = jobExplorer.findJobInstancesByJobName(jobName, 0, 1);
        if (jobInstances.size() > 0) {
            List<JobExecution> jobExecutions = jobExplorer.getJobExecutions(jobInstances.get(0));
            if (jobExecutions.size() > 0) {
                JobExecution jobExecution = jobExecutions.get(0);
                JobParameters jobParameters = jobExecution.getJobParameters();
                Optional<Long> blockNumber = Optional.ofNullable(jobParameters.getLong(paramKey));
                if (blockNumber.isPresent() && blockNumber.get().equals(paramValue)) {
                    if (jobExecution.getStatus().equals(BatchStatus.STARTED)) {
//                    throw new RuntimeException("waiting until previous job done");
                        log.info("waiting until previous job done ... : {}", jobName);
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public Long getStartNumberFromBatch(String jobName, String batchMode, String paramKey1, String paramKey2, long defaultValue) {
        List<JobInstance> jobInstances = jobExplorer.findJobInstancesByJobName(jobName, 0, 20);
        ArrayList<Long> failExecutionNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Long> successExecutionNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<Long> successEndExecutionNumbers = new ArrayList<>();
        ArrayList<JobExecution> executions = new ArrayList<>();
        jobInstances.stream().map(jobInstance -> jobExplorer.getJobExecutions(jobInstance)).forEach(jobExecution -> {
            JobParameters jobParameters = jobExecution.get(0).getJobParameters();
            Optional<Long> param1 = Optional.ofNullable(jobParameters.getLong(paramKey1));
            Optional<Long> param2 = Optional.ofNullable(jobParameters.getLong(paramKey2));
            if (param1.isPresent() && param2.isPresent()) {
                if (jobExecution.get(0).getExitStatus().getExitCode().equals("FAILED")) {
                    failExecutionNumbers.add(param1.get());
                } else {
                    successExecutionNumbers.add(param1.get());
                    successEndExecutionNumbers.add(param2.get());
                }
            }
        });

        if (failExecutionNumbers.size() == 0 && successExecutionNumbers.size() == 0) {
            return defaultValue;
        }

        long successMax = defaultValue;
        long failMin = defaultValue;
        if (successEndExecutionNumbers.size() > 0) {
            successMax = Collections.max(successEndExecutionNumbers);
        }
        if (failExecutionNumbers.size() > 0) {
            failExecutionNumbers.removeIf(successExecutionNumbers::contains);
            if (failExecutionNumbers.size() > 0) {
                failMin = Collections.min(failExecutionNumbers);
            } else {
                return successMax;
            }
        }
        if (Objects.equals(batchMode, JobValidator.batchMode.RECOVER.toString())) {
            return Math.min(failMin, successMax);
        } else {
            return Math.max(failMin, successMax);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would not consider that as a memory leak (and definitely not is Spring Batch's code). The way you are checking things like `isExistLatestRunningJob`  involves retrieving a lot of data that is not really needed. For example, the method `isExistLatestRunningJob()` could be implemented with a single database query instead of retrieving `10000` job instances with:

```
List<JobInstance> jobInstances = jobExplorer.findJobInstancesByJobName(jobName, 0, 10000);
```

A query like the following should work:

```
SELECT E.JOB_EXECUTION_ID from BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION E, BATCH_JOB_INSTANCE I where E.JOB_INSTANCE_ID = I.JOB_INSTANCE_ID and I.JOB_NAME=? and E.START_TIME is not NULL and E.END_TIME is NULL
```

Adding to that that your method is called every 500ms.. Clearing the lists does not necessarily clear memory at the time you might expect.

So I think you should find a way to optimize the way you retrieve data by doing the filtering on the database side instead of the application side.

Answer (score 0):

I debugged your code.
The problem is your enum field var is defined as public and not static.
I think It's will make serious problem, If you reference this var in another class.
Define enum field as static or private.
I hope find solution.

Comment: Thanks. You were right. It works. But is not that all. I am trying to another solution.